# Counting Records With Spacial Condition

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, counting

I have many Excel files which contain records of many schools students like...

Name | Father Name | Class | Section | Address | Image Path | Mobile No. | House Name | Gender *etc*...

[image: screenshot]

So I want to count records by class wise with consider gender & house in Excel or in Access

House Name & Class Name differ in different schools.

If Class Name & House Name are same in every school than it is simple to write VBA code or a formula in Excel like....

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet!K2:K500="L.K.G.")*(Sheet!AB2:AB500="Male"))
```

it works

but every time (I have many excel file) I am not sure about K2: K500 for class, AB2:AB500 for gender (also Z2:Z500 for house) and also not sure about class name.....
different school write class like.......

```
1 Shishu Vatika 1 Nursery       1 Prep
2 KG A          2 KG I      2 LKG
3 KG B          3 KG II     3 UKG
4 I             4 First     3 I
etc...
```

So I can not write in formula =”Nursery’’ (Nursery is a school name)

I am also not sure about house name...

Different schools write house names like...

```
1 Gandhi            1 Peace     1 Rani Laxmi Bai
2 Nehru         2 Joy       2 Mother Teresa
3 Subhash               3 Charity   3 Meera Bai
4 Tagore            4 Hope      4 Jija Bai
etc...
```

So I can not write in formula `="Peace"` (where "Peace" is a House name)

But I am sure about column header like...

Gender, House Name, Class or Full Class

So I want to write a macro in Excel or in Access which provide me one click solution without thinking about class name, house name gender column name (A, B, Z etc) & in the result of macro create a new sheet for counting result in excel (in excel macro) or create a new table in access for counting result in access (in access macro) see my result table below

[image: Another screenshot]

I'd prefer to write an Excel macro but am prepared to use MS Access. Please can you help me to get started with this?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the SUMIF(S) instructions.